# Searching for App "Presence" written in Vala

Tags: vala

I think it was called "presence" or something like that. Anyway if anyone either knows the right name, (Google comes back with nothing), or where I can find it (The last place I remember was Gitorious). Then I would be grateful.

Edit:
Since found out that it is indeed called "Presence".

Comment: I found it on gitorious

Answer (score 1):

*Adding a answer for future reference*

The Git Repo the user is talking about is found [here](https://gitorious.org/valastuff/presence/)

Unfortunately, as of writing this repo looks to have been abandoned over 4 years ago.

The last release was [presence-0.4.8](https://gitorious.org/valastuff/presence/?p=valastuff:presence.git;a=commit;h=0ed7de15af0d796a2207e0d628fadebe7b999314)

The last log update was 2012-09-04

Further References:

- [https://lists.fedoraproject.org](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2015-March/209034.html)
- [http://www.mail-archive.com](http://www.mail-archive.com/package-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg38507.html)
- [http://www.rpmfind.net](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/x86_64/p/presence-0.4.8-15.fc26.x86_64.html)
- [https://bugzilla.redhat.com](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=855636)
- [http://www.filewatcher.com](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/presence-0.4.8-14.fc24.i686.rpm.62898-0.html)